# Excel, how to change a string of text showing as constant into a true formula?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I modified some excel formula using another formula, after done so, I copy and paste special on to overwrite the original range.  But they are now showing as constant.  I have to manually hit `F2` and then `return key` to get that evaluate.

Here is an example:

- A2 originally has the formula `=IF(ISNUMBER(B2),B2,0)`
- then I use a custom function to extract the formula if A2 as text string in order to modify it into `=B2`
- Now I copy and paste the result back to column A, paste special as Formula
- A2 is now showing as `=B2` as a string/constant, rather the actual value of cell B2
- After I hit `F2` and `Enter`, A2 now resolved the true value of B2.

How can I fix this without manually doing this? There are thousands of rows!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this with the find/ replace in the edit menu , select the relevant cells, for example find “(B2)” and replace with “(C2)”.

One way I speed it up is to replace “=if” with “xyxyif” to stop recalculation, then once all ready replace “xyxy” with “=“ ...

Comment: It works! Not the most sophisticated solution, but works perfectly.

Comment: What I did was

 - highlighting the cells/range in question (luckily this is in a column, not spreading around)
 - search and replace all the `=` with string like `xxyyttzz` within the highlighted range
 - search and replace all the `xxyyttzz` back to `=`
 - Baaam! all done!

Answer (score 1):

Can you check calculation option is set to automatic or manual. If not set to automatic then set it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select any cell in column A or select the entire column and try this:

With VBA:

```
Sub test()

' If you know the range, just change "Selection" with the actual range or column

With Selection

    With .EntireColumn

    .TextToColumns , DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    End With

End With

End Sub
```